# Getting a file by serverrealtive url is raising this error "Server relative urls must start with SPWeb.ServerRelativeUrl"

Tags: development, sharepoint-rest-api, 2019

We have a SharePoint onpremsies 2019, and inside it we have a site collection as follow:-

```
https://ourcompany.com/sites/ABC
```

so we are trying to get the details of attachment inside a list named Invoices, as follow:-

```
https://ourcompany.com/sites/ABC/_api/web/getfilebyserverrelativeurl('/Lists/Invoices/Attachments/1/PDF_200001.pdf')?$expand=Author&$select=TimeCreated,Author/Title,Author/Email,Author/Id
```

but we got thsi error:-

[image]

any advice please?

I tried to remove the "/" from the beginning of the serverrelativeurl but this raised another error.. any advice?

Thanks

Comment: Try using URL `/sites/ABC/Lists/Invoices/Attachments/1/PDF_200001.pdf`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Server relative" means you have to start the URL after the host name, so the *server* relative URL of that file would be

```
/sites/ABC/Lists/Invoices/Attachments/1/PDF_200001.pdf
```

What you currently have is the *site* relative URL, because `/Lists/` is relative to whatever subsite you happen to be under.